# error in pipenv setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

When I try to pipinstall pipenv I get the following error:

```
nathan@DESKTOP-KKB4QL2:/mnt/c/Users/Nathan/Dropbox$ pip install pipenv
Downloading/unpacking pipenv
  Downloading pipenv-11.7.1.tar.gz (5.0MB): 5.0MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_nathan/pipenv/setup.py) egg_info for package pipenv
    error in pipenv setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    error in pipenv setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_nathan/pipenv
Storing debug log for failure in /home/nathan/.pip/pip.log
```

I've tried to update pip, but that just resulted in an exception.

Comment: Not enough information. Please, tell us the versions of Python, setuptools and pip. Show us your `setup.py`. *I've tried to update pip, but that just resulted in an exception.* — show us the exception.

Comment: I suspect something is broken in a recent release. I have the same problem with the latest versions but I was able to install an older version `pip install pipenv==11.0.0`. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: I was able to install with pip install pipenv==11.0.0 as well

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you are using the correct version of pip. It's likely your pip defaults to 2.7, you can try pip3.6 or find in your system any/all versions of pip.

I had this exact issue when I tried

```
pip install --user pipenv
```

which was fixed when I tried (On MacOS sierra)

```
sudo -H pip3.6 install -U pipenv
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. This happened to me on my RPi1 which had python 3.4 but I was trying to install something that required 3.8+.